# C# Selenium sendkeys

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to submit a list of strings at once rather than individually via a text file, using sendkeys in selenium by findelement.

Example of usage:

```
 driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys(line);
```

What I'm using at the moment is a foreach loop to iterate through the list sending a request with the current line/string individually:

```
            foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(@"input.txt"))
            {
                string search = line;

                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("search")));

                if (driver.FindElements(By.Name("search")).Count != 0)
                {
                    driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys(search);
                }

                driver.FindElement(By.Name("srchbtn")).Click();

                Results();
            }
```

however the site allows upto 100 strings per search, so rather than sending 1 string each request, I would line to send 100.. How would I extract the first 100 strings from my text file and input them as a list into sendkeys, then the next 100 lines and so on..

I did try:

```
 var Lines = File.ReadLines(@"input.txt").Take(100).ToList();

 driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys(Lines);
```

but it returned a error stating:

```
 cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the string before sending

```
var query = string.Join(" ", Lines);

driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys(query);
```

Comment: I need each string to be on a new line :/

Comment: replace  " " with Environment.NewLine